# How to compare two columns from results of another query?

Tags: sql, mysql

Table:

| id | sequence | destination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | Johannesburg |
| 2 | 2 | Durban |
| 2 | 3 | Cape Town |
| 3 | 1 | Queenstown |
| 3 | 2 | East London |
| 3 | 3 | Gqeberha |

When I search for "Queenstown" in the `destination` column I would like to get:

| id | sequence | destination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | East London |
| 3 | 3 | Gqeberha |

I want records where `sequence` is greater than that of the queried record of which `id` is the same.

Comment: Please show us your current query and explain what is not working with it.

Comment: Thing is I dont have a clue on where to begin but when do the following `SELECT * FROM destinations WHERE destination = 'Queenstown'` the result should be like those on the second table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a self-join:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.sequence > t2.sequence
WHERE t2.destination = 'Queenstown'
ORDER BY t1.sequence
```

`t1.id = t2.id` makes the `id` the same, and `t1.sequence > t2.sequence` makes the sequence higher than the current record.